# execute code after link is loaded

Tags: jquery, anchor, ready

There is an anchor tag with a link. So when I click on the link and all the new content loads I want to execute one line of code which opens the desired slide from slider. Is there an event for this?

EXPLANATION:

```
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">Gallery</a>
<a href="#" id="button-about">About</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
```

Homepage holds the slider.

```
$('#button-about').click(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        slider.goToSlide(5);
    });
});
```

User is in Gallery. When user clicks "About" button, home page is being loaded and fifth slide is being opened. Since Gallery doesnt hold slider, it has to shoot an event after the home page DOM is being loaded and then go to slide number 5.

Comment: How would that work? That adds an event handler for `ready`, but only once you've clicked a button. At that point, `ready` is already been and gone. If you want something to happen when a page loads, put it straight in `ready`.

Comment: If you want the slider to activate after an AJAX call has finished, you would need to attach to the AJAX completion event.

Comment: I need an event to trigger after a specific link is clicked, not all of them. If im still wrong give me a snippet.

Comment: what does `specific` mean? All we see is code that will run on all elements with same class.

Comment: I apologise if I wasnt clear enough. I changed the main message, I hope it is clear enough.